# PHP – find file in an unknown directory by making the call from an external directory file

Tags: php

I am working with a file call update.php where the procedure will auto update some files in the same update directory, but I need to access the install.inc file that is in the apps sub-directory called install.  The problem is that the apps directory name can be change by the system admin or by the original installation setup process.  I would like to create a procedure in the update.php file to determine if the apps directory name was changed and if it was, how do I get the new apps directory name so I can include it into the procedure for the require_once file path?

Comment: does the file's name change at all? or can the admin change that too so it migth be `foo/bar.php` originally, but afterwards it could be `argle/bargle/oogah/boogah.php`?

Comment: No the file name remain the same: foo/bar.php originally, but after it could be wahever/bar.php

Comment: `exec('find /start/path -name bar.php')`, or use a [directoryiterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the real path with:

```
<?PHP
  echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"];
?>
```

You can comare the "normal" path with this one.